# With my script, checkboxes are not functioning like radio buttons

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script originally written by Ben Collins that I have modified to fit my needs.  This script unchecks the boxes on edit to another checkbox in the specified range.  The script works well when the checkboxes are in cells B5:D5.  See script below:

```
/**
 * onEdit to uncheck checkboxes as required
 */
function onMySecondEdit(e) {
   
  // get event object data: sheet name, row number and column number
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  const row = e.range.rowStart;
  const col = e.range.columnStart;

  // Row 5, Columns 2 through 4
  if (e.range.rowStart > 4 || e.range.rowStart < 6 || e.range.colStart > 1 || e.range.colStart < 5 ) {

  switch(col) {
 
    // case when column B is checked
    case 2:
      sheet.getRange("C" + row + ":D" + row).uncheck();
      break;
 
    // case when column C is checked
    case 3:
      sheet.getRangeList(["B" + row,"D" + row]).uncheck();
      break;
     
    // case when column D is checked
    case 4:
      sheet.getRange("B" + row + ":C" + row).uncheck();
      break;
 
    // cell is outside of columns B to D
    default:
      return;
  
  }
  }
}
```

I have a simple `onEdit` trigger installed to run this script.  Works great.  However, when I try to duplicate this script, changing the range to K12:M12 the checkboxes no longer function like radio buttons.  I have examined it carefully, editing and re-editing to try to figure out where the error is in the code, but cannot figure it out.

Here is the modified script.  I am using onEdit() in this one but have tried a simple trigger as well.

```
/**
 * onEdit to uncheck checkboxes as required
 */
function onEdit(e) {
   
  // get event object data: sheet name, row number and column number
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  const row = e.range.rowStart;
  const col = e.range.columnStart;

  // Row 12, Columns 11 through 13
  if (e.range.rowStart > 11 || e.range.rowStart < 13 || e.range.colStart > 10 || e.range.colStart < 14 ) {

  switch(col) {
 
    // case when column K is checked
    case 2:
      sheet.getRange("L" + row + ":M" + row).uncheck();
      break;
 
    // case when column L is checked
    case 3:
      sheet.getRangeList(["K" + row,"M" + row]).uncheck();
      break;
     
    // case when column M is checked
    case 4:
      sheet.getRange("K" + row + ":L" + row).uncheck();
      break;
 
    // cell is outside of columns K to M
    default:
      return;
  
  }
  }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of my spreadsheet:

[image: Screenshot]

I suspect that it is something minor that I have done wrong, and I just need a second set of eyes to look it over and find the mistake.  I know there are other requests for help with checkboxes and radio buttons on here, but I am merely wondering what error I am making in this particular script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not working as intended on your script as the number of columns stated on your switch statement reads the wrong column number.

In the script below the expression is `col` which refers to the number of columns. The value of the column is compared to the value of each case. I changed the case number to the responding column number for K,L,M.

```
/**
 * onEdit to uncheck checkboxes as required
 */
function onEdit(e) {
   
  // get event object data: sheet name, row number and column number
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  const row = e.range.rowStart;
  const col = e.range.columnStart;

  // Row 12, Columns 11 through 13
  if (e.range.rowStart > 11 || e.range.rowStart < 13 || e.range.colStart > 10 || e.range.colStart < 14 ) {

  switch(col) {
 
    // case when column K is checked
    case 11:
      sheet.getRange("L" + row + ":M" + row).uncheck();
      break;
 
    // case when column L is checked
    case 12:
      sheet.getRangeList(["K" + row,"M" + row]).uncheck();
      break;
     
    // case when column M is checked
    case 13:
      sheet.getRange("K" + row + ":L" + row).uncheck();
      break;
 
    // cell is outside of columns K to M
    default:
      return;
  
  }
  }
}
```

### Reference:

[Switch](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp)

Comment: Thank you.  Never used `Switch` before.  That was the issue.

Comment: You're welcome! I hope the article also helps to further understand the `switch` statement.

Comment: Yes, thank you.  I have that site bookmarked as it is an invaluable reference.